# How to correctly manage TextViews and ImageViews so they don't use a lot of RAM?

Tags: android, performance

I have an android app that consists mainly of TextViews and a few ImageViews, it also has some buttons all coded into the xml. I have 4 fragments and a MainActivity, each fragment is its own screen for use with a bottom navigation bar. The problem is: My app will take as much as 340mb of ram on my physical device, I could not find any resources that explain how to properly load images and text so that they don't take so much RAM. Can anyone share some resources on RAM management for android?

Comment: How do you know the memory consumed come from your views instead of your bad logic memory alloc code?

Comment: I have no memory alloc code. I dont know how to do that which is why I'm asking for resources for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you some tips to decrease your memory usage:

```
- Flatten your layout, less using nest layout
- Instead of using many TextViews for layout, use can use less TextView combine with Html.from(format your text like htlm> 
- Scale your load image to a lower size
- Limit your memory leak, use this Leakcanary
- Dump your memory usage by using Dump Memory in Android Profiler of Android Studio, so that to find out variables that used most memory.
```

That all! I think these is enough for you to troubleshoot memory and increase your app's performance. Hope this help.

Comment: memory leak must be removed completely from project. a bit of memory leak is danger.

Comment: html.from() is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Android studio has a tool called [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) which allows you to profile and monitor the memory usage of your app. You could make a judgement from there on what consumes most memory of your phone.

My guess is the images you load. You probably need to sample and resize the images when you load them. It is common to use library such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to handle it for you.

Here is another article on Android, [Manage your app's memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory) could give your some information on how to manage your app memory in general.